# Why dont show kendo ui grid validation on editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Why not show grid validation to me on editor template on editing field?
I don't understand why not reading data annotation.
Sorry for bad english language...

At first I created kendo grid like this:

```
  <div id="grid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CardView>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(x =>
    {
        x.Bound(c => c.CardID).Title("Card Nm.");
        x.Bound(c => c.ExpirationDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");//.EditorTemplateName("KendoDatePicker");
        x.Command(cmd =>
        {
            cmd.Edit();
        }).Title("Edit");
    })
        .BindTo(Model)
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Model(model =>
                      {
                       model.Id(x => x.CardID);
                      })
                     .ServerOperation(true)
                     .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Home"))
                     .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                     .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Home"))
 .Editable(editable =>editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)))
</div>
```

Here is javascript which is using in datasource event error:

```
<script>
 function error_handler(e, status) {//Klaidu isvedimas
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Error:\n";

            var grid = $('#GrdKendo').data('kendoGrid');
            var gridElement = grid.editable.element;

            var validationMessageTemplate = kendo.template(
                "<div id='#=field#_validationMessage' " +
                    "class='k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation " +
                        "k-invalid-msg field-validation-error' " +
                    "style='margin: 0.5em;' data-for='#=field#' " +
                    "data-val-msg-for='#=field#' role='alert'>" +
                    "<span class='k-icon k-warning'></span>" +
                    "#=message#" +
                    "<div class='k-callout k-callout-n'></div>" +
                "</div>");

            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if (value.errors) {
                    gridElement.find("[data-valmsg-for=" + key + "],[data-val-msg-for=" + key + "]")
                        .replaceWith(validationMessageTemplate({ field: key, message: value.errors[0] }));
                    gridElement.find("input[name=" + key + "]").focus();
                }
            });
            grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();   // cancel grid rebind
            });
        }
    }
```

When I created my **viewModel**(validation on CardID working, but dont working on expirationDate which using editor template):

```
public class CardView
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Card Expiration Date")]
    public virtual string CardID { get; set; }
    [UIHint("DatePicker")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Card Expiration Date")]
    public virtual DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I created editor template in **Views\Shared\EditorTemplates** location with name **DatePicker.cshtml** :

```
    @model DateTime?
    @(Html.Kendo()
    .DatePicker()
    .Name(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName.ToString())
        .Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"))
```

So how to read data annotacion on editor template field?
Data annotacions works perfect on field which is not using editor template

Answer (score 5):

I found solution(searched about two days). Need add Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("Validation", ViewData.ModelMetadata) in html attributes in editor template

Here is code:

```
@model DateTime?
@(Html.Kendo()
.DatePicker()
.Name(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName.ToString())
.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
.HtmlAttributes(Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("Validation",     
 ViewData.ModelMetadata))
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. You should mark this as the answer.